# Single array re-indexing for table formatting

Tags: java, c#, arrays, loops, slice

I am looking for a more elegant solution to the following scenario (language doesn't matter, Java is fine, but I am currently in C#). Suppose a linear array is coming in and being displayed as a table with X items per row (For instance, 9 items coming in at 3 items per row, so 3 rows of 3). If the array is being indexed 0 through 8, it is currently displayed as such:

6  7  8

3  4  5

0  1  2

So, the elements are displayed left to right, bottom to top. I would like to rearrange this to be displayed top to bottom, like this:

0  1  2

3  4  5

6  7  8

This requires reordering the array so that the new array's indexes are [6,7,8,3,4,5,0,1,2], with respect to the original's indexes. My current (untested) solution is the following: assume the array to be returned is 'array' and a temporary copy is 'temp', and the 'cols' variable is already the number of items per row.

```
int rows = (array.Length + cols - 1) / cols; //ceiling function to determine rows needed
        int pos = array.Length - cols;  //starting position in index transfer
        int offset = 0;                 //needed when negative index reached
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                if (pos + j >= 0)
                    array[cols * i + j - offset] = temp[pos + j];    //assign values of temp to array
                else
                    ++offset; //takes care of negative indeces
            }
            pos -= cols;
        }

        return array;
```

The problem is this code is quite unreadable and possibly inefficient because of the double loop, though I don't expect many more than 9 items to come through. Is there a more elegant solution to this using slicing up the array, reversing, or anything that isn't so difficult to read? It's just a fun little problem I've been thinking about for an issue at work. Anybody's input is appreciated, thanks!

It is worth noting that potentially uneven tables can be created (For instance, 9 elements with 4 items per row creates 2 rows of 4, one row of 1. The 'offset' variable is used to protect negative array indexing if this is the case).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:  it doesn't sort your original array at all, but every inner loop starts at a computed starting-index based on the row you're printing.  Let me know if you have any questions.  This isn't specific to you, more specific to your situation, but the concept and functionality is there.

```
int[] array = new int[9] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

int rows = 3;
int cols = 3;

int count = 0;
for (int x = 1; x <= rows; x++)
{

    int startingPos = array.Length - (x * rows);
    for (int y = cols; y > 0; y--)
    {

        Console.Write(array[startingPos] +", ");
        count++;
        startingPos++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```